# How to add several records to firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I tried to add a few records to firestore, but new record is overwriting previous.

My code

```js
await this.$fire.firestore.collection('saveups').doc(uid).set({
  title: payload.title,
  amount: payload.amount
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.collection().add()` instead of rewriting the same `doc(uid)`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Comment: but how can I save userID (uid)?

Comment: @LevVorobev it's not too clear what your question is. if you want multiple documents related to the same id, then store that on the document itself. `.collection('saveups').add({ userId: uid, title: payload.title })`